# LateInitializationError error in firebase auth code in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Pro(),
      child:MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );

  }
}


class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  final FirebaseAuth auth= FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initUser().whenComplete((){
      setState(() {
      });
    });
  }
  _initUser() async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      await auth.currentUser?.reload();
      Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 2),
            () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        MainScreen(user!)),
                    (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
      );
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1),
              () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          MyHomePage()),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Splash Screen"),
        ),

    );
  }
}
```

The auth authentication code. I wrote again, but I was advised to use Future . But I use Splash Screen and I don't know how to code it. Below is the error

```
The following LateError was thrown building MainScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<Pro?>], state: _MainScreenState#23216):
LateInitializationError: Field '_instance@21075166' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MainScreen MainScreen:file:///F:/flutter%20project/good_man/lib/main.dart:78:25
```

It seemed to be a problem with the mainscreen, but the same error appeared when I deleted the variable called user with the mainscreen. I've heard advice that it seems like a problem with the destruction cycle of auth and user .

Comment: replace Late _instance to _instance?

Comment: Try to use for e.g `Late String` to `String? yourvarName` then add your condtions

Comment: Stop reposting your question.